# How to verify the axioms for an abelian group?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

$$ x \Leftrightarrow y = \begin{cases}1 &: \text{for } (x,y) \in \{(1,1),(0,0)\}\\
0 &: \text{for } (x,y) \in \{(1,0), (0,1)\}\end{cases}
$$

**Question**: How to verify the axioms for an abelian group?

**associative**:

$(1,1) \rightarrow (1,1),$
$(0,0) \rightarrow(0,0),$
$(1,0) \rightarrow (0,1),$
$(0,1) \rightarrow (1,0)$

**neutral element**: $1$

How can I verify if all elements are invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an inverse for each element (which isn't much work in this case). Thus, **for every** element $x$ , you have to find an element $y$ that acts like an inverse. In quantor notation:

$y = x^{-1} \iff  \exists y : x*y = y*x = 1$

Comment: So an element can be the inverse to itself?

Comment: Yes that's certainly possible. For example, the neutral element is always its own inverse, but it can also happen with other elements.